# how to identify the subject related to the verb in complex sentences?

Tags: verbs, subjects, complex-sentences

Here is the sentence in question:

> In 2014, Norton publicly backed "Hacked Off" and its campaign toward UK press self-regulation by "safeguarding the press from political interference while also giving vital protection to the vulnerable

How do we understand here who is safeguarding the press? Is it Norton, that bakes "Hacked Off" by safeguarding the press? Or it is the campaign that achieves UK press self-regulation by safeguarding it?
It would be also useful to know the corresponding grammar rule for cases like this and more examples of sentences like that.

Comment: The key here is the phrase **its* campaign*. The inanimate pronoun "it". Not the human pronoun "he", as would be applied to Norton. Also "Hacked Off" is capitalized, so it's a proper noun, meaning it can be a referent. Therefore Hacked Off has a campaign to blah blah blah, and Norton publicly backed that entity (Hacked Off), and therefore, indirectly, its campaign to blah blah blah.

Comment: I see your point, but even taking that into account the sentence still confuses me. It is clear that the part "its campaign toward UK press self-regulation" refers to "Hacked Off". But it is not clear whether the next part - "by safeguarding..." refers to the action of Norton or to the way the campaign enacted self-regulation.

Comment: There's no way to determine that grammatically; could be either. You have to go to the semantic or pragmatic level. Contextually, *could* it be both? Is it more likely to be one or the other? In this case, to "back a campaign" usually means to "contribute money to the campaign in order that it more effectively or efficiently achieve its objectives". One does not typically "back" a campaign "by safeguarding....". In fact, "safeguarding the press from ..." is something a campaign *would do*, and is consonant with the description of the campaign's objectives of "UK press self-regulation".

Comment: Also, if the writer meant that Norton safeguarded, a comma before 'by' would force that interpretation.

Comment: Dan, thanks. I guess this kind of reasoning will naturally come as I learn English further.

Comment: Aml, indeed, good point.

Comment: @stroks Just for the sake of transparency, I’m a native English speaker, and upon reading your quoted sentence, I didn’t *consciously* go through the kind of analysis I described above. It was all subconscious and immediate, so the conscious experience was simply understanding what was said. I’m sure you do the same in your native tongue. To explain it to you, I had to go back and think about why I concluded what I did. And I think as you develop in English, you will not develop this kind of conscious mental reasoning per se, but you will find yourself understanding more statements naturally.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two cents: The conjunction "and" makes ""Hacked Off" and its campaign toward UK press self-regulation" a single object. Norton, the subject, "backed" it.

In 2014, Norton publicly backed "Hacked Off" and its campaign toward UK press self-regulation by "safeguarding the press from political interference while also giving vital protection to the vulnerable.

Comment: That isn’t just unclear: it’s largely unintelligible.
Norton seems to have backed *"Hacked Off" and its campaign toward UK press self-regulation* was reasonably clear but *by safeguarding…* spoiled everything.

I suggest it isn’t reasonable to suppose either Norton or Hacked off was safeguarding anything…

The main clues to this are  the retention of *by* which serves no purpose but to confuse, and the clever construction *press self-regulation by "safeguarding the press.”*

How could Norton or Hacked Off  have safe-guarded the press or given vital protection to the vulnerable, please?